# Common Lisp: How to use a macro within a macro?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I'm writing an application (a simple game) using cl-sdl2. cl-sdl2 includes a macro called `WITH-EVENT-LOOP` that can be used to start the SDL application with some event handlers.

Currently I use the macro like so:

```
(sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
  (:idle () (on-idle :renderer renderer
                     :tick-func tick-func
                     :render-func render-func))
  (:quit () t)

  ;; Input handlers below
  (:keydown (:keysym keysym)
            (funcall input-func :keydown :keysym keysym))
  (:keyup (:keysym keysym)
          (funcall input-func :keyup :keysym keysym)))
```

This code listing is small because I omitted several more input handlers. There are at least 6 more handlers defined following this same pattern, for handling mouse and game controller input events, so my actual code is longer and highly repetitive.

I can write a macro that generates these boilerplate forms:

```
(defmacro forward-evt-to (target evt &rest evt-args)
  `(,evt ,evt-args
         (funcall ,target ,evt ,@evt-args)))
```

This produces a list that can be understood by `WITH-EVENT-LOOP`:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(forward-evt-to input-func :keydown :keysym keysym))
(:KEYDOWN (:KEYSYM KEYSYM) (FUNCALL INPUT-FUNC :KEYDOWN :KEYSYM KEYSYM))
T
```

But when I try to use that macro, I get a compiler error. For example this fails:

```
(sdl2:with-event-loop (:method :poll)
  (:idle () (on-idle :renderer renderer
                     :tick-func tick-func
                     :render-func render-func))
  (:quit () t)

  (forward-evt-to input-func :keydown :keysym keysym)
  (forward-evt-to input-func :keyup :keysym keysym))
```

`WITH-EVENT-LOOP` tries to compile the code without expanding it and gives the error

```
; The value
;      INPUT-FUNC
;    is not of type
;      LIST
```

Is there any way I can use my `FORWARD-EVT-TO` macro from inside the `WITH-EVENT-LOOP` macro? I can't/don't want to modify `WITH-EVENT-LOOP` directly.

Comment: In general, macros can only be used in places where an expression will be evaluated. Since the clauses of `WITH-EVENT-LOOP` aren't evaluated, you can't use a macro to expand into a clause.

Comment: You might be able to do something using read-time evaluation with `#.`. But since the expansion shouldn't be evaluated, it needs to return a quoted list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to write a new macro, which expands into your target form.

Sketch of an example:

```
CL-USER 8 > (defmacro with-event-loop-1 (foo &body clauses &environment env)
              `(with-event-loop ,foo
                                ,(loop for clause in clauses
                                       when (keywordp (first clause))
                                         collect clause
                                       else
                                         collect (macroexpand-1 clause env))))
WITH-EVENT-LOOP-1

CL-USER 9 > (pprint
             (macroexpand
              '(with-event-loop-1 (:method :poll)
                 (:idle () (on-idle :renderer renderer
                                    :tick-func tick-func
                                    :render-func render-func))
                 (:quit () t)
                 
                 (forward-evt-to input-func :keydown :keysym keysym)
                 (forward-evt-to input-func :keyup :keysym keysym))))

(WITH-EVENT-LOOP (:METHOD :POLL)
  ((:IDLE NIL (ON-IDLE :RENDERER RENDERER
                       :TICK-FUNC TICK-FUNC
                       :RENDER-FUNC RENDER-FUNC))
  (:QUIT NIL T)
  (:KEYDOWN (:KEYSYM KEYSYM) (FUNCALL INPUT-FUNC :KEYDOWN :KEYSYM KEYSYM))
  (:KEYUP (:KEYSYM KEYSYM) (FUNCALL INPUT-FUNC :KEYUP :KEYSYM KEYSYM))))
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Just one question, as someone new to Lisp, why use `MACROEXPAND-1` instead of `MACROEXPAND` in `WITH-EVENT-LOOP-1`?

Comment: MACROEXPAND would possibly expand it multiple times, until the top form can't be expanded anymore. That can be useful. Here I assume that the provided macro already creates the final code -> the code we want to include in the underlying WITH-EVENT-LOOP form. Then expanding it once is sufficient.